# Отправка письма от другого email в laravel

Tags: laravel

Отправляю письмо с помощью smtp аккаунт google
Письмо приходит, все работает
Встал вопрос, как реализовать отправку письма с любого другого email адреса
На сайте есть форма обратной связи с указанием email адреса, нужно отправить письмо с email адреса, который указан в форме, нужно это для удобства ответа на письмо.

В .env использую данные от google почты

Пробовал отправлять таким образом -

```
Mail::raw('Текст письма', function($message)
{
  $message->from('test@mail.ru', 'Николай');//Тут подставляем другой mail
  $message->sender('test@mail.ru', 'Николай');
  $message->returnPath('test@mail.ru');
  $message->to('info@site.ru')->subject('Заявка');;
});
```

Указывал действующий email адрес отправителя, письмо приходит от email адреса, который указан в настройках .env, как сделать, чтобы письмо пришло от `test@mail.ru`?

Comment: письмо упадет в спам (нужно ли оно вам)